# T-SQL function that returns TABLE using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, dynamic-sql

EDIT: Some of those who would offer help are unclear about the nature of the requirement, so I will try to state it as clearly as I can:

We need to instantiate a view of an underlying table, and this view must be able to be joined to another table; the difficulty is that *the identity of the underlying table is not known until runtime of the ad hoc query doing the join*.
We would like to do something like this:

```
  select * from foo
   inner join dynamicallyInstantiatedTable(condition) DT
   on foo.zipcode = DT.zipcode
```

It doesn't seem possible to create a function that returns TABLE if the function uses dynamic SQL. This is not valid:

```
   declare @tablename varchar(50);
   -- <snip> code to determine the name of @tablename

   declare @statement varchar(1000);
   set @statement = 'select * from ' + @tablename;
   exec( @statement);
```

The error:

> Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a
>   function.

*If the table name is not known beforehand for whatever reason* (e.g. tables are constantly being added  and we must select against the most recent one, say), is it possible to do the select dynamically and return a table, either in a stored proc or function?

Comment: Can the SP return the table so that it could be treated as a table, that is, the stored proc name acts as a tablename in another select statement? `select * from myproc inner join T....`

Comment: [SELECT * FROM @tablename](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_table)

Comment: @Tim Ah, I see what you're asking.  Unfortunately, no, you can't do that in either a stored procedure, view, or function.  The closest you can get is a procedure that returns a resultset, but you can't treat it as a table.

Comment: Some really ugly way `SELECT  * FROM    
OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'EXEC MyProc @parameters')` combined with dynamic SQL may work, But still I wouldn't go that way

Comment: **`tables are constantly being added and we must select against the most recent one`** It indicates table per date, which is IMHO poor design. And it is antipattern [SELECT * FROM sales + @yymm](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Sales_yymm)

Comment: You can't do **ANY** "side affecting" operations in a function. Meaning, you can't execute dynamic sql in a function.

Comment: @lad2025: I understand. It's far from optimal, but we're getting large tables sent to us by business partners daily, and I don't want to dump them all into a single table, and don't have time to write an application because this is a temporary situation that will last only a couple of weeks. The OPENQUERY approach might work. Sometimes the real world is messy.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go.

I don't use synonyms often, but CREATE SYNONYM supports dynamic SQL.

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(128);
-- <some code to set @tablename>

declare @sql nvarchar(500);

if object_id(N'dbo.TodaysData', N'SN') is not null
    drop synonym dbo.TodaysData;

set @sql = 
    'create synonym dbo.TodaysData
     for ' + @tablename;

execute(@sql);

select top 5 
    *
from 
    dbo.TodaysData as t
    join
    dbo.SomeOtherTable as s
        on 
           s.FieldName = t.HeresHopingYourSchemaDoesntChange
```

Comment: Very creative! I like the dynamic use of the synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL in function. No.

> is it possible to do the select dynamically and return a table, either
>   ***in a stored proc*** or function?

Perhaps I'm missing something (would not be a first) but this seems simple as a stored proc:

**The Proc**

```
create proc dbo.getRowsFrom @tablename varchar(50) as
exec('select * from ' + @tablename);
```

**Use**

```
exec dbo.getRowsFrom '<my table>';
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I need to join <my table> to another.

Comment: Ah - ok. Makes sense. Stored proc is out too then. The OPENQUERY solution that lad2025 posted may be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you should once explain your requirement with example.It is not clear to anybody.

I think everything thing can be done within single proc,no need of another proc or UDF.

```
declare @tblname varchar(500)
select  @tblname=name from sys.objects
where type_desc ='USER_TABLE'
order by create_date DESC

declare @Sql varchar(max)=''
set @Sql='select * into #tmp from '+@tblname+'  '

set @Sql=@Sql+' select *  from #tmp   drop table #tmp'
exec (@Sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Little detail given about your 'join' situation, but it might be easier to jump to your final joined results, rather than focusing on the input table in isolation.

Here I am joining my input table 'a' to a lookup table 'ref', and outputting joined results.
If tomorrow your have another input table 'b' - this proc will join that to the lookup table instead.
The only requirement is that the join column is consistent.

```
  declare 
  @inputTableName nvarchar(128)
  ,@sqlExec nvarchar(max)

  set @inputTableName = 'b';

  if(not exists (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema = 'test' and TABLE_NAME = 'myView'))
  begin
        select @sqlExec = 'create view test.myView as 
                            select I.*,R.[text] from test.[' + @inputTableName + '] I inner join test.ref  R on I.col0 = R.col0'
end else begin
        select @sqlExec = 'alter view test.myView as 
                            select I.*,R.[text] from test.[' + @inputTableName + '] I inner join test.ref  R on I.col0 = R.col0'
end
    exec (@sqlExec)

select * from test.myView
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, Simon. I have to run but will check later and circle back.